# Can't reset my password: strange link given in the "account recovery mail"

Tags: support, login

I want to reset the password of the only Stack Exchange account I created some years ago. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) asks my email; I type it in and click on the "Send Recovery Email" button. Then I get an email sent by `"Stack Overflow" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com>`. In this mail, I read the following sentence :

> If you initiated this request, click this link to reset your password.

The words "click this link to reset your password" contain a link pointing to https://stackjava-script.com/users/login?ssrc=account_recovery. A strange page appears with a French message having nothing to do with Stack Exchange.

So, what's going on here?

Comment: I just created a new account and then requested account recovery. In the email I receive it links to `https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=%2fGOz...` so I have no repro now. Is it possible that you have a local issue or a rogue ISP? Maybe a virus. Try a different computer and/or email client. The domain you linked to is also using an invalid certificate and the domain doesn't look to be registered by Stack Overflow: https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=stackjava-script.com

Comment: @rene The SSL certificate issue appears to have been fixed, they're using Let's Encrypt now.

Comment: @KevinBrown at least that is fixed and the website has a great explanation why you might end-up there.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

We've received similar reports on and off over the last couple of years.

The short version of the problem is "your email provider is an idiot". They blindly replace the word "overflow" with "java-script". Why? No idea. But I found a similar report [here](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/7):

[image]

If you fix the URL manually (the domain should be stackoverflow.com, of course), you should be able to reset your password.

Comment: Incredible. And yes, my email provider is ... Orange.

Comment: Oh that's funny. But somebody must have caught on to take advantage, I mean, stackjava-script dot com is certainly a registered domain name. Btw the ovh (the registrar) abuse complaint form is at https://www.ovh.com/ca/en/abuse/

Comment: @JasonC I'm not sure there's a real abuse case here. That domain isn't fishing (or phishing) for our users' credentials, or pretending to be Stack Overflow. It just happens to exist.

Comment: @AdamLear Maybe OVH caught onto the issue and added it to be the good guy.

Comment: This looks like [a really bad attempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem#Blocked_emails) to sanitize input. (We can't blame the website for this.) We might as well be in the *Medireview* Ages.

Comment: @Laurel Indeed. It's a [clbuttic](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-), time-honored approach.

Comment: And here comes the real question: what theme are you using for GitHub?

Comment: @Braiam https://userstyles.org/styles/37035/github-dark

Comment: Reminds me of when AOL [blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) the UK town of Scunthorpe many years ago...

Comment: It looks like someone has bought the stackjava-script.com domain now and put a nice message explaining what is going on.

Comment: Funny. Imagine the abuse potential if the provider used `javascript` instead of `java-script`.

Comment: They surely have some `Brillant` developers